# Parsing dynamic site

Tags: python

Task: to get the text of posts from the Instagram account.
The Instagram page is dynamically generated, so I can only get the first few posts. I know that I can scroll the page using Selenium, but I do not understand how to include selenium in this code. Are there any other ways?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import json
import re


url = 'some url'
page = requests.get(url)


html = soup( page.text, 'html.parser')
s = str(html)
r = re.compile('"shortcode":"(.*?)"')
result = r.findall(s)
print(result)


for shortlink in result:
    print ("https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/"+shortlink)
    response = requests.get("https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/"+shortlink)

    todos = json.loads(response.text)
    print(todos['title'])
    print("---------")
```

Comment: you can use `Selenium` instead of `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` because it will read page and it has own functions to search in html. Or you can use `Selenium` instead of  `requests` to get html using `driver.page_source()` and then use it in `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Instagram API, there is even a [python module](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram) for it.

Comment: I don't want to depend on Instagram API.
I've tried this code ``` from selenium import webdriver import time 
from lxml import etree,html 
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get("url") 
time.sleep(10) 
page = driver.page_source with open("output.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f: f.write(page) driver.close() ```